# ACCESS 2010 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table `tblSupplierCriteria`. I can populate it from a form that consists of the Supplier Name followed by a dropdown box that lists 46 criteria.

The user selects one of the criteria and then clicks on save. In the table, the saved record looks like - Supplier1 nuts, the next record looks like Supplier1 bolts and so on.

Each Supplier can have between 1 and 46 records. Each is added one at a time. The form works fine but it is tedious. Is there a way that I can display all 46 items at one time and let the user choose by clicking a check box or something and then populate the `SupplierCriteria` table as described above?

This is part of a highly integrated application and I cannot modify any of the table structures.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you can display the criteria in a dropdown box, you can display them all in a pop-up form so someone can tick them off.

If you can create a local table, you can copy the 46 criteria from the central data to the local table, and add a Yes/No column so you can record what the user picks.

Base your pop-up form off of the local table. Populate `SupplierCriteria` based on their choices.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Thank you for the feedback.